# Scrolling in Matlab brings up error "MEvent. CASE!"

Tags: matlab, scrolling

Any time I scroll left, right, or to the edge of an up or down scroll, I get the error "MEvent. CASE!" in Matlab. It's really annoying because it happens even if I barely move my two fingers left or right as I'm sliding them down on the touchpad on my laptop.

Comment: This is a known issue with Matlab, you can find more information [here](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/112528-mevent-case-when-two-finger-scrolling?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how general this is, but this works on my Ubuntu 16.04 with Synaptic Touchpad.

1. Run `xinput list` in terminal to find Touchpad IDs.

   ```
   test@laptop:~$ xinput list
   ⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ```

   i.e. here relevant entries are id=11 and id=15.
2. Check Two-Finger Scrolling settings by running `xinput list-props 11` and `xinput list-props 15` which are responsible for the "MEvent. CASE!" error in MATLAB.

   ```
   test@laptop:~$ xinput list-props 11
       Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (278):   1, 1

   test@laptop:~$ xinput list-props 15
       Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (278):   1, 1
   ```
3. Disable horizontal scrolling by

   ```
   xinput set-prop 11 "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0
   ```

   and

   ```
   xinput set-prop 15 "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0
   ```

   If this works you can create a `startup.m` script in your MATLAB startup directory which is automatically executed each time you open MATLAB.

   ```
   system('xinput set-prop 15 "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0');
   system('xinput set-prop 11 "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0');
   ```

To find your MATLAB startup folder where you want to put the `startup.m` file, write `pwd` in your MATLAB console.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Hunter suggested on a Mathworks forum, simply create a file `startup.m` with instructions that switch off horizontal scrolling:

```
!synclient HorizEdgeScroll=0
!synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
```

You may need to open an editor as admin to be able to save to the folder, e.g. `sudo gedit`. Paste the two lines above into the fresh file and save as startup.m in your `MATLAB/R201.../toolbox/local/` folder.